# How to optionally capture a group inside a bigger regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse a text file using regexes, but I am failing at capturing part of the file, that is optional. I thought it will be simple (and surely is), but my initial attempt failed. Then I started playing with lookarounds, but that failed as well.

Here's example of how the file looks like:

```
block of text that also have some bits that have to be matched / captured
OPTIONAL_TEXT_1 1234 5678 91011
OPTIONAL_TEXT_2 9876 5432 1098
some more text that also has bits I need in it
```

There is always at least one of those optional lines (first, second or both). What I want to capture are last numbers in either of these lines (in this case 91011 and 1098).

I am trying to use single big regex to match everything at once, because all data I need always have certain structure and it should be easier to write single one.

Initially, I've tried this approach:
("…" marks the rest of the regex that works properly, also, I've "newlined" the code here, to increase readability, it's a single line originally)

```
…
.*?(?:OPTIONAL_TEXT_1(?:[^\r\n]+) (\d+)\n)?
.*?(?:OPTIONAL_TEXT_2(?:[^\r\n]+) (\d+)\n)?
…
```

This approach partially fails - both groups `(\d+)` return nothing, regardless of whether there's only single or both optional lines, but at least the rest of regex catches everything correctly.
I am guessing, that making outer group a non capturing one affects inner one.

My second approach was using lookarounds (after I've read a bit about it, as I knew literally only that there is something like that):

```
…
.*?(?<=OPTIONAL_TEXT_1(?:[^\r\n]+) )(\d+)?(?=\n)
.*?(?<=OPTIONAL_TEXT_2(?:[^\r\n]+) )(\d+)?(?=\n)
…
```

It works only, when both lines are there. Otherwise whole regex fails to capture anything.

P.S.

Regex options I am using are these:

```cs
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline
```

Comment: Like this? `^block of text .*(?:\r?\nOPTIONAL_TEXT_\d+.* (\d+))+` https://regex101.com/r/O2SM2b/1

Answer (score 1):

If the text is optional then you can also omit it.

You could extend the pattern that matches the first bits that have to be matched, and then match all lines that end with a space and 1 or more digits.

Then get the group values from the [Captures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=net-8.0):

```
^block of text .*(?:\r?\n.* (\d+))+$
```

If the text at the beginning of the line is not optional:

```
^block of text .*(?:\r?\nOPTIONAL_TEXT_\d+.* (\d+))+
```

The first pattern matches:

- `^block of text .*` The first part of your pattern
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `.* (\d+)` Match the rest of the line, and then a space and capture 1+ digits in group 1
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat it 1+ times to match at least a single line
- `$` End of string

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Fjgye2) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1A3lWJ/1)

For example

```
string pattern = @"^block of text .*(?:\r?\n.* (\d+))+$";
string input = @"block of text that also have some bits that have to be matched / captured
OPTIONAL_TEXT_1 1234 5678 91011
OPTIONAL_TEXT_2 9876 5432 1098
some more text that also has bits I need in it";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
{
    foreach (Capture capture in m.Groups[1].Captures)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(capture.Value);
    }
}
```

Output

```
91011
1098
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove RegexOptions.Singleline so . does **not** match newline and add RegexOptions.Multiline so you can use ^ and $ instead of \r and \n and then code something like this:

```
(?:OPTIONAL_TEXT_1|OPTIONAL_TEXT_2).* (\d+)$
```

If the optional text is always at the beginning of a line then add an up-arrow (^) to the beginning of the regex.

The text you want will be in capture group 1.